# Unable to save video anymore with Expo on iOS

Tags: expo

I have an Expo App (iOS/Android) that allow the user to record short videos (and pictures) and share them (among other things). It worked fine on both OSes for a while, but recently it stopped working on iOS (Android still working fine). Picture taking works fine on both devices.

Here is the code that used to work when trying to save said video :

```
const recordPromise = this.camera.recordAsync({
    maxDuration: 5,
    quality: Camera.Constants.VideoQuality["720p"],
});

const videoData = await recordPromise;
let asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(videoData.uri);
```

The following error is raised on createAssetAsync() :

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Asset couldn't be saved to photo library]
```

Recording itself seems to be fine (uri has been anonymized) :

```
Object {
    "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540app%252Fapp/Camera/0F46F276-DCBE-4999-A3E0-0E10955467AF.mov",
}
```

Permissions are requested in componentDidMount and had been granted  :

```
    const permissionCamera = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    const permissionLibrary = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
    const permissionMicro = await Camera.requestMicrophonePermissionsAsync();
```

When checking the permissions for Expo Go in the settings, they are properly allowed.

MediaLibrary.getPermissionsAsync(); returns :

```
{
  "accessPrivileges": "all",
  "canAskAgain": true,
  "expires": "never",
  "granted": true,
  "status": "granted",
}
```

Same code worked perfectly a couple weeks ago, and is still working fine on Android. I thought that it was an Apple-related change, but found nothing in the documentation or internet.

Expo CLI version is 4.10.1, SDK 42, iOS is 14.8 but the issue has been witnessed on multiple different devices.

Expo Go is up to date, I even uninstalled Expo Go and reinstalled it just in case. Didn't tried that failing version in testflight (some account stuff that needs to be handled with Apple before we can publish anything again), but I need this to work again in expo go anyway.

Nothing in that file has been changed for almost 120 days.

I made a bare app that reproduce the same issue. Code can be found here : https://github.com/sebastien-f/expo-test-video

Comment: Seems that the issue is coming from camera.recordAsync(), specificaly from the quality settings that made the video not being recorded at all (hence the file is probably of 0 length which might cause the error). Still investigating the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is create by camera.recordAsync() that stops almost as soon as it starts. Only happens when the quality prop is used. For now, I've removed the parameter and opened an issue on Github : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/14432